# How to programmatically execute Node app in the background

Tags: node.js

I am making a node-app for the terminal but I want it to run on the background process on the terminal just as it works with:

`$ my-app &`

I'm using the following requirements

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var app = require('commander');
var notifier = require('node-notifier');
var moment = require('moment-timezone');
var at = require('node-at');
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Possibly related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/363311/is-it-possible-to-allow-a-background-process-to-continuously-output-to-terminal

Comment: On what OS/platform?

Comment: MacOS 10.12.6 :)

Answer (score 0):

use spawn:

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const myApp = spawn("node", ["my-app"]);
```

You can then use the myApp variable to subscribe to process events such as `exit` and pipe streams to the process.

N.b "child_process" comes with node.js so is not a new package dependency.

[This](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/node-js-child-processes-everything-you-need-to-know-e69498fe970a) is a useful primer.